# Arch Linux: Finding out build-dependencies so they can be turned into AUR dependencies

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, aur

I'm using the Arch Linux and trying to create an AUR file that would download the source of a driver, compile and install it. What I wonder is - how can I check which packages are required for the compilation to succeed (just so I could declare those dependencies in my AUR)? Do I really have to analyze the very long `configure` file or is there a better way?

**Edit:** or maybe I'm not supposed to add build-dependencies to the usage dependencies in AUR?

**Edit #2:** I'm trying to create AUR for this: http://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/6258/ACS-Unified-Driver-Lnx-Mac-113-P.zip

Comment: That depends on the type of configure script it uses.  `autoconf` produces `configure.log` which is easier to parse, but few kernel drivers use `autoconf`.  On the other hand most kernel drivers have simple configure scripts or, sometimes, not even have a configure script (just a makefile).  It might be useful to post which driver you want to compile (i believe it is not your own, since then you would know the dependencies).

Comment: @grochmal I added link to the source.

Comment: Hey! You did not read the README :) . It is there in the first couple of lines there:  You need `pcsclite 1.8.3 or above`, `libusb 1.0.9 or above`, `flex`, `perl` and `pkg-config`.  Let me just dig out one of my AURs and i'll write something on how to check for things like libraries from a readme.

Comment: omg, you are right, I'm ashamed ;_; . Thanks, that would be helpful :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most packages want to be helpful when installing them so they will have some dependency information in the `README` or the `INSTALL` file.  Otherwise yes, checking the `configure` script it the only real option (Note: `autoconf` produces `configure.log` that enumerates dependencies, and several other configure scripts print a dependency summary at the end to make this easier for packagers).

For the problem at hand the README is most useful, it says:

```
Linux
- pcsclite 1.8.3 or above
- libusb 1.0.9 or above
- flex
- perl
- pkg-config
```

Now, let us have a look at that.  An AUR package can assume that `base` and `base-devel` groups of packages are installed, which make things easier to reason about.  Enumerating the dependencies we see:

- `pkg-config`: is in `base-devel`, we do not need to care about it.
- `perl`: is part of `base`, fine.
- `flex`: `base-devel` again.
- `libusb 1.0.9 or above` and `pcsclite 1.8.3 or above`

  ```
  pacman -Ss libusb
  core/libusb 1.0.20-1
      Library that provides generic access to USB devices

  pacman -Ss pcsclite
  community/pcsclite 1.8.16-1
      PC/SC Architecture smartcard middleware library
  ```

The beauty of a rolling forward distribution is that you can assume that the user has the latest packages (if he is a sane user he will do `pacman -Syu` before installing your AUR package).  Therefore we can simply do (inside `PKGBUILD`):

```
depends=(libusb pcsclite)
```

---

Extra note: Sometimes it is not as easy to find the package a `README` or `INSTALL` talks about.  In this case **google-fu** is needed.  Yet, arch also has `pkgfile` which is the database of which files are in which packages.

For finding dependencies to be added to AUR packages I strongly recommend installing `pkgfile`, i.e.

```
pacman -S pkgfile
```

And then you can query suspicious packages for libraries, e.g.

```
pkgfile -l <package> | grep lib
```